# PHP speed up replace?

Tags: php

How can I increase the performance of the following code:

```
$text = str_replace("A", "B", $text);
$text = str_replace("f", "F", $text);
$text = str_replace("c", "S", $text);
$text = str_replace("4", "G", $text);
//more str_replace here
```

Comment: Is this really the slowest part of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as one function call:

```
$text = str_replace(["A","f","c","4"], ["B","F","S","G"], $text);
```